# Is "einen der" in "Hinter mir seht ihr einen der berühmtesten Imbissstände" accusative or genitive?

Tags: grammatical-case

I'm a bit confused about this sentence because *Imbissstände* is plural, but *einen* is singular accusative and I'm not sure if *der* is plural genitive or masculine nominative.

Comment: "einen" is singular, because you only see *one* "Imbissstand", not all of them. In English, you use singular as well: "Here you see one of the most famous ...".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Einen" is accusative singular

"der Imbissstände" is genitive plural

> Ihr seht einen Imbissstand aus der Gruppe der berühmten Imbissstände

That is, one out of many.

Answer (score 5):

```
┏━━ADVERBIAL━━┓  ┏━PREDICATE━┓ ┏━SUBJECT━┓ ┏━━━━━━━━━ACCUSATIVE OBJECT SINGULAR━━━━━━━━━━┓
  Hinter mir      seht        ihr       einen  der berühmtesten Imbissstände.
                                              └──────GENITIVE PLURAL NOUN PHRASE─────┘
```

Behind me you're seeing one of the most famous snack stalls.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assume that both should have the same case? *Einen* is in accusative singular, while *der* in genitive. Notice that *der* cannot be nominative, because the noun is in plural (Imbissstände).