# Superlative form with “meist”?

Tags: adjective, comparison

I’m learning German by watching a movie, which is about a Hacker *Who am I — No system is safe*. I came across this sentence which confuses me:

> Ich bin einer der meist gesuchten Hacker der Welt.

My questions are:

1. what is the role of *einer* here?
2. my understanding about superlative adjective is: unlike in English, it can never be formed by *meist-* + adjective. But here is *der meist + gesuchten Hacker* <=> the most wanted hacker, it’s similar to English.

It is not clear to me why we use *einer der meist + adjective* here?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30952/is-einen-der-in-hinter-mir-seht-ihr-einen-der-berühmtesten-imbissstände-accu (May even answer your question)

Comment: Shouldn't the proper word be _meistgesuchten_, without a space?

Comment: gesuchten? i found in dictationary that "gesucht" is an adj, but here it makes me think about a verb in perfect tense (ge...en). pls explain, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sentence is almost 1:1 same in English:

> I am **one** of the **most wanted** hackers in the world.
>
> Ich bin **einer** der **meistgesuchten** Hacker der Welt.

Please notice, that this word is *written together* (thank you user_unknown) - keep reading for explanation.

Your confusion might result of the fact, that English superlatives are built using *most* (*most beautiful*, *most powerful*), whereas in German not (they are build with *am ---sten*, for example *am schönsten*).

Actually, ***meist*** is the superlative of *viel* (used as adverb in the meaning of *frequent*, see definition II [here](https://de.thefreedictionary.com/viel)). Saying *vielgesucht* is perfectly correct and meaning *searched a lot* (or, in this context *much wanted*).

To complicate things a little more, we sometimes write things in German together, sometimes not. If written together, mostly a second meaning appears, often metaphorically. A nice example of this phenomenon is:

> **neuer Wagen** (a *newly bought* car)
>
> **Neuwagen** (a *new, just produced* car)

Same thing here:

> **meist gesucht** would mean *mostly wanted* (but sometimes also not wanted)
>
> **meistgesucht** means *most wanted*

[Further reading](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/meist) [Further reading 2](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Adjektiv.html)

Comment: Your second example about snowmen is not the very best. Colours are not gradable, "am weißesten" is colloquial. You could use "kalt" (cold) but "kalt" is directly gradable "am kältesten" and "am meisten kalt" does not sound right for a native German (me).  I would propose the two sentences "Schneemänner sind im Sommer meist benachteiligt " (Snowmen are usually disadvantaged in the summer) and "Schneemänner sind im Sommer am meisten benachteiligt "  (Snowmen are most disadvantaged in the summer) or something in that line.

Comment: So lucky for me when being with a native German, thanks @deamentiaemundi

Comment: Ein meist gesuchter Verbrecher ist einer, der auch ab und zu nicht gesucht wird, aber meist wird er gesucht. Im Ggs. dazu ist ein meistgesuchter Verbrecher einer, der am intensivsten Gesuchten.

Comment: Völlig korrekt! Ich werde meine Antwort entsprechend ändern.

Comment: No, German superlatives are not *generally* created with *am –sten*. This applies to the superlatives of *adverbs*. *Adjectives* form their superlatives with a simple *ste*: »Die läng*ste* Antwort« (not: »die am längsten Antwort«).

Answer (score 0):

1 Einer here is "one" in the sentence "one of the most wanted Hacker"

2 Im not sure , but the Adj "gesuchten" is "Partizip II" , und with Partizip 2 adj you use the Meist+adj to give superlative  .